# How to handle invalid login details to a SQL database from a webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I have a web app which contains a modal for the use to enter the details to the SQL server they want to connect to. If the user enters correct details it works as intended.

Currently if a user enters incorrect value I get the following error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Login failed for user 'S'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I am trying to handle the case of the user entering incorrect log in details. The details being passed through are server, database, username and password. My expected result would be that the user is alerted if they enter invalid details

The desired outcome would be for the modal to display that the connection details have been entered incorrectly.

This is the test connection method where I hit the error on con.Open

```
public static bool TestConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit an error"); 
                return false;
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use website credentials for for SQL Server Login credentials. There's so many things wrong with this approach you're using that I don't know where to begin. Instead, your web-application should have a single **secret** SQL Login entry - unless your requirements differ.

Comment: @Dai That is the requirements for the application yes. I just want to be able to handle the case of the user entering incorrect login details when targetting a specific database,  thisi s due to the web app containing a table with data from the database

Comment: So create an account for the web app to use, and use *that* to connect to the database on the user's behalf. Your web app should be responsible for making sure users are accessing appropriate content. Databases are not good at such things.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're facing here. You appear to have client side code to pass the login info to the server. What issue are you actually facing? You don't know how to check the credentials on the server side? You don't know how to show a popup? Which part are you actually seeking help for?

Comment: @mason I am seeking help for checking the credentials, I have a test connection method  which I will add to the question. It is in this method where I recieve the error in the original post

Comment: If you're seeking help checking the credentials, then why did you provide us with client side JavaScript code? So with the server side code...you're getting an exception. You know how [exceptions work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/)? You know about [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)? By the way, that check to make sure the State is Open is unnecessary. If you call the Open() method and you don't get an exception, it's safe to assume the connection is open.

Comment: @mason Not fully confident with exceptions or try catches. What would be the best way to set up this exception and try catch for this ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I provided? It explains what goes in the try block (the code that might throw the exception). In the catch block in this case, you can `return false;`